# Bash variable that gives the parameters used in each function call, similarly to BASH_SOURCE and FUNCNAME

Tags: shell-script

I wrote a shell script function to mimic a Stack Trace printer as high level programming languages do when reporting an error.

It displays the function call stack printing pairs of the shell source script and the function name for each call stack element. For that I use [bash variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) `BASH_SOURCE` and `FUNCNAME`.

I wanted to further improve this by adding the parameters at each function call. By have not been able to accomplish that, tried using `BASH_ARGV`, but it seems to refer to the arguments passed at the topmost call only.

Anyway I can achieve that ?

Comment: Have you tried to check the actual `$0`, `$1` etc variables? They are probably still unchanged on the last function call.

Comment: That would require an array of arrays, which bash does not implement.